# HPLIP can't add tray icon

Tags: 15.04, kubuntu, autostart, system-tray, hplip

I am using HPLIP 3.15.9 on Kubuntu 15.04. It is started automatically after login and tries to add an icon to the system tray... but this does not work most times and I get an error dialog instead, that tells me HPLIP is unable to find a system tray (while I can clearly see the tray).

I found many suggetions in the web that are based on delaying the startup of HPLIP. However either they didn't work (modyfing some loop in a HPLIP script) or I could not apply them since they worked with older OS version only.

How can I solve that problem?

If delaying is a solution, where can I find the auto start entry of HPLIP? I looked in system settings of Kubuntu but the list of auto-started applications does not contain HPLIP (I suppose it is auto-started by some file based mechanism I am not aware of).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround for the problem. The file /etc/xdg/autostart/hplip-systray.desktop needs to be edited.The line `Exec=hp-systray -x` must be changed to `Exec=sleep 30;hp-systray -x`

Comment: Still works on Kubuntu 19.10. On Kubuntu, I didn't experience the issue described in the OP, although I did see it on plain Ubuntu with Gnome desktop. But I am hoping this hack will solve a different issue: sometimes the HP driver can't connect with the printer. I think it is just a matter of timing, with the driver sometimes starting too early, before the printer is available to the system.